# Random sampling, what is the error in my reasoning

Tags: probability

Taken from Ross, first course in probability, question 11, chapter 1, self-evaluating questions:

From 10 married couples, we want to select a group of 6 people that is not allowed to contain a married couple
Books answer, which I agree makes total sense:
[image: image of answer]

My answer is different,:
First pick has 20 choices, second 18, etc, giving 20*18*16*14*12 = 967680
Of those, we divide by 5! to remove dupicates (or fiveplicates I should say) of sampling, where ABCDE is the same group as EDCBA
That gives me 8048

What is the error in my reasoning?

Thanks

Christian

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but your arithmetic is off!

First off, we are choosing $6$ people. $20 \times 18 \times 16 \times 14 \times 12$ represents $5$ choices though. Instead we need $20 \times 18 \times 16 \times 14 \times 12 \times 10$. Further, we will divide by $6!$, not $5!$ to remove the 'sixplicates'. So, we have that 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{20 \cdot 18 \cdot 16 \cdot 14 \cdot 12 \cdot 10}{6!} = 13440
\end{equation*}
Hope this helps

Comment: That was a stupid mistake, thanks for pointing it out!